# Overriding `from my_module import ...`

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I am trying to get the following behavior to work:

```
from my_module import some_random_string
```

and my module should intercept that and return certain values based on `some_random_string`.

I have tried setting up an import hook but it's not working as expected:

```
# custom_import.py
import sys

class MyImporter(object):
    def find_module(self, filename, path):
        print(filename, path)
        return "foobar"

    def load_module(self, module_name):
        print(module_name)
        return "foobar"

sys.meta_path.append(MyImporter())
```

```
# interactive console
>>> from custom_import import some_string
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name some_string
>>>
```

Why is that and how do I fix this?

Comment: Import hooks override the importing of modules only; importing a particular name from the module is then done via normal attribute lookup.  You would need to replace the module's entry in the `sys.modules` dict with a custom object that overrides attribute lookup - sorry, I don't have an example handy, and I'm not sure that this can be done from within the imported module itself.

Comment: @jasonharper If that’s the case then I wonder [how this worked](https://github.com/drathier/stack-overflow-import).

Comment: `some_random_string` is an exact name of an object or do you mean that you can do `from my_module import qsSdGa2rsd` to work?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov some_random_string is whatever string I want to pass in to the custom importer. I would like to be able to import pseudo modules just like the link in my previous comment.

Comment: does `my_module` exist?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Yes, that would be module that handles the “pseudo” object loading.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to import any object which is not present in `my_module` (assuming that `my_module` exists and accessible) we can start from simple wrapping `my_module` like

```
import importlib
import sys
import types


class ModuleWrapper:
    def __init__(self, module):
        self.module = module

    @property
    def __path__(self):
        return None

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return getattr(self.module, name)
        except AttributeError:
            # returning `module` object is not necessary, 
            # can be something else
            return types.ModuleType(name)


my_module = importlib.import_module('my_module')
sys.modules['my_module'] = ModuleWrapper(my_module)
```

### Test

With project structure

> **my_module.py**
>
> **test.py**

And contents

- **my_module.py**:

  ```
  ...snippet above...
  some_name = 'Sample text'
  ```
- **test.py**:

  ```
  from my_module import some_name, z

  print(some_name)
  print(z)
  ```

executing

```
> python test.py
```

gives us in **Python2.7.0**

```
Sample text
<module 'z' (built-in)>
```

and in **Python3.5.4**

```
Sample text
<module 'z'>
```

Comment: I guess it can work by defining the module directly with `sys.modules`. One down side is that the string has to match the file name exactly. Now the question is that why `sys.meta_path` didn’t work. If it worked for the GitHub repo I linked then it should also work here, isn’t it? Unless I’m missing something important.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: what do you mean by 'string has to match the file name exactly'? if we are defining `ModuleWrapper` inside of `my_module` then we can obtain module name like `ModuleWrapper.__module__` and replace `'my_module'` literal with that

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: if I understood correctly there is no need in creating custom `Importer`, it will be the way if there was no `my_module` and we wanted something like `from some_valid_but_non_existent_module_name import some_valid_object_name`

Comment: What if I also want this to work: `from some_module.some_path_a import some_path_b` where `some_path_a` isn't a real module? Is it possible to get that to work too?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: it will be great if you describe desired behavior in this case in detail